# How to backup solution folder before releasing the new build to on-premise server in Azure CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I would like to keep the solution backup to some folder before releasing the new build in my Azure CI/CD pipeline. And to deploy the solution, I am using my on-premise server. Not sure where to make changes to save existing artifacts to some folder before getting the new release.

This way we can avoid the failure if something goes wrong to current release. We can have the backup to copy the file.

[Release Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7JZZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to keep the solution backup to some folder before releasing the new build in my Azure CI/CD pipeline.

Based on your requirement, you can use the [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the existing files on the server to the target folder.

Here are the steps:

Step1: you can check the IIS deployment Physical path in IIS web app manage task.

For example: `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`

[image]

Step2: you can add the Copy file task at the top of the Release Pipeline. Then you can set the Physical path and target folder to copy the existing files.

For example:

[image]

In this case, when the release pipeline is running, it will backup the existing files first and then it will deploy new files to local server.

On the other hand, since you are using CI/CD pipeline, the related files will be saved in Build artifacts. You just need to change the build artifacts version in Release Pipeline, then you can deploy the previous artifacts again.

[image]